# How to delete quotation marks in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am working on Test First Ruby with rspec examples testing...

which I need to pass this test.

```
it "tokenizes a string" do
    calculator.tokens("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /").should ==
      [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
  end
```

And here is my code

```
def tokens(str)
    data = str.split(' ')
    outcomes = []
    data.collect do |x|
      if x.to_i != 0
        outcomes.push(x.to_i)
      elsif x.to_i == 0
        temp = x.gsub('"', '')
        outcomes.push(":#{temp}")
      end
    end
    outcomes
  end
```

However, I got these feedback. Have no idea how to get rid of the quotation mark.

```
Failure/Error: [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]                                                                                                                               
       expected: [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]                                                                                                                                  
            got: [1, 2, 3, ":*", ":+", 4, 5, ":-", ":/"] (using ==)
```

Comment: By the way, your code has a bug: you cannot enter a `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
outcomes.push(:"#{temp}")
```

`":#{temp}"` is string but this `:"#{temp}"` symbol with string interpolation.

```
=>:"+".class
#> Symbol
=> ":+".class
#> String
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote you up yet :（

Answer (score 3):

The problem are not the quotation marks. Quotes mean that the element is a `String` type, your spec expects a `Symbol`.

```
outcomes.push(":#{temp}")
```

should be

```
outcomes.push(temp.to_sym)
```

To give you an idea

```
2.1.2 :006 > :*.class
 => Symbol 
2.1.2 :007 > ":*".class
 => String
```

Comment: actually just `temp.to_sym`

Comment: I try to change it like this, but the result still the same,

'elsif x.to_i == 0
        temp = x.to_sym
        outcomes.push(":#{temp}")
      end'

Comment: @SimoneCarletti got it figured out, thanks for your help

Comment: This should probably be `outcomes.push(x.to_sym)`. `temp = x.gsub('"', '')` was the OP's attempt to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Simone Carletti already provided a [solution for your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26926872/477037) (using [`to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-to_sym)), but you can further improve your code:

- `split(' ')` can (in this case) be replaced with [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-split) (without arguments)
- instead of `elsif x.to_i == 0` you can use `else`
- [`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-collect) (or `map`) already creates and returns an array, you just have to provide the values

Applied to your code:

```
def tokens(str)
  str.split.map do |x|
    if x.to_i != 0
      x.to_i
    else
      x.to_sym
    end
  end
end
```

You can even write this in one line using a [ternary if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if):

```
def tokens(str)
  str.split.map { |x| x.to_i != 0 ? x.to_i : x.to_sym }
end
```

You might have to modify your condition, since `x.to_i != 0` returns `false` for `x = "0"`.

Comment: How about `if x =~ /^[+-]?\d+$/` in place of `if x.to_i == 0` to squash the bug @JörgWMittag mentioned? Yumiko, in a real app, you also need to worry about bad data. For example, "9cats".to_i => 9`.

Answer (score 1):

`":#{temp}"` generates a String that starts with a colon.

But you want to translate your `temp` string to a symbol, like this `temp.to_sym`. Or you want to build a symbol like this: `:"#{temp}"` (note that the colon is in front of the string).